Relaunch a terminal using a terminal command
Today, to convert from Markdown to PDF using Pandoc, it was necessary to install pdflatex.
I did brew install basictex and then it was necessary to relaunch Terminal. For this, I simply closed it and opened it again. But is it possible to relaunch it using a command, something like relaunch terminal?

The zsh shell has a built-in command, rehash, which makes the shell forget all remembered ("hashed") locations of executables. This allows it to discover new executables you may have installed during the lifetime of the current shell session.
I believe it would be better to use rehash than to try to relaunch the terminal.  That is, if it is due to not finding the newly installed pdflatex command you ask the question.
